# What is alternative to `variant.resValue` with AGP 7.0.0+?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to migrate to Android Gradle Plugin 7.

I have the following code that needs migration:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  // do some processing to obtain string apiKeyValue
  variant.resValue "string", "api_key", apiKeyValue
}
```

I have looked at the migration blog post here [android developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/12/announcing-android-gradle-plugin.html) but still no clear reference to how to create dynamic

> resValue

Any thoughts?

I also tried to use something similar to

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
      // do some processing to obtain string apiKeyValue
      addResValue("api_key", "string", apiKeyValue, "Value from variant")
    })
}
```

But no luck as

> addResValue

method is not found.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching and trial and error, the following code worked for me:

```
androidComponents {
  onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
    // do some processing to obtain string apiKeyValue
    variant.resValues.put(variant.makeResValueKey("string", "api_key"), new ResValue(apiKeyValue, "Variant Name"))
  })
}
```

The above code is a snippet from my ***build.gradle*** file. I took inspiration from here [gradle-recipes](https://github.com/android/gradle-recipes/tree/agp-7.0/Kotlin/addCustomResValueField)

Answer (score 1):

For groovy and AGP 7.2.1 old way still works. Only keys for resValues now have type prefix ie `"string/app_name"`. instead of `"app_name"`.

```
android{
    applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
        def strRes = variant.mergedFlavor.resValues.get("string/app_name")
        if(strRes != null){
            println( "string/app_name = " + strRes.getValue())
            variant.resValue 'string', 'app_name', "${strRes}New"
        }
    }
}
```